# How to get field names from a tbl_dbi?

Tags: r, dbplyr

Is there a  way to directly get the field names from a `tbl_dbi` object (`db_mtcars` below)?

```
 library(RSQLite)
 library(dbplyr)
 library(dplyr)
 con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
 dbWriteTable(con, "mtcars", mtcars)

 db_mtcars <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes with `colnames()`

```
> colnames(db_mtcars)
 [1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear"
[11] "carb"
```

Comment: Any idea why?  Why does this work where `names()` fails.  Both colnames's underlying function `dimnames()` and `names()` are primitives... so it doesn't look like there is some S3 dispatch going on.

Comment: @russellpierce `colnames` falls back to `dimnames` when x is not a data frame, and `dbplyr:::dimnames.tbl_lazy` does indeed do S3 dispatch to return the appropriate column names by peeking into the lazy tbl object.

Answer (score 3):

`colnames(db_mtcars)` is the easy solution, `DBI::dbListFields(con, "mtcars")` is the fancy solution.
Both work even when `names(db_mtcars)` fail.